# How to do a de-warping that generated by a fisheye image in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, fisheye

Is there any inbuild functionality that I can use to de-warp an image from fisheye to normal image?

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what MSalters said, you'd first go and [calibrate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera) your camera, to get the cam-matrix and the distortion coefficients.

then you'd run [undistort()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20undistort%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20InputArray%20newCameraMatrix%29) to rectify the fishEye image.

again, you need the camera-mat and the distCoeffs to do it, so if that image was taken with a different camera, and you're lacking that information, - you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `undistort()`. "The function transforms an image to compensate radial and tangential lens distortion." IIRC, a fisheye camera has rather extreme radial distortion.

Comment: Thanks. Since fisheye images have extreme radial distortion, I am not sure I can use the above mentioned function to de warp them.

Comment: I have used undistort() along with parameters computed from calibration to do this with a 180deg fisheye lens, and it works okay. The major caveat is that I got much better results when the calibration was done in a single plane. I sometimes got nonsense when I used parameters computed from images of arbitrarily oriented checkerboard patterns.